# Idiom for "trying to figure something out"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

In Swedish, we have an idiom that goes, "to suck on the/that caramel [for a while]" and is used either when you need to contemplate a decision ("I'll have to suck on that caramel for a while before deciding.") or to try and figure something out ("He had been sucking on that caramel just as long as I had, but neither of us had an answer.")

I can't find a good English equivalent to the second meaning of the idiom, but I'm sure there is one.
So, **I need an idiom for trying/having tried to figure something out (without luck, so far.)**

Answer (score 4):

A similar idiom in English: "I'll have *to chew on* that for a while."

How it may affect your dental health compared to sucking caramal is debatable.

Less interesting, but gets the job done: *to mull* something over.

Comment: This answer has the merit of being metaphorically similar.

Comment: Also [*chew it over*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chew-sth-over).

Answer (score 2):

I think ***[rack one’s brain](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rack-ones-brains)*** may fit in your context:

> to strain in mental effort, esp to remember something or to find the solution to a problem.

(Collide Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

**think something over**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/think+it+over) an idiom:

> - to think about something and whether one will choose to do it.

- I need a few minutes to think it over. Let me think over your request
  for a day or so.